# Bash - How to shorten username in PS1

Tags: bash, users, prompt, useradd, uid

Currently my prompt is:

```
xiaobai@dnxb:/tmp$
root@dnxb:/tmp#
```

My desired prompt:

```
xb@dnxb:/tmp$
rt@dnxb:/tmp#
```

My idea is alias of username, so i tried reuse the same uid to create a new user:

```
xiaobai@dnxb:~$ sudo useradd -ou 1000 -g1000 -d /home/xiaobai -s /bin/bash xb
xiaobai@dnxb:~$ su
Password: 
root@dnxb:/home/xiaobai# passwd xb
Enter new UNIX password: 
Retype new UNIX password: 
passwd: password updated successfully
root@dnxb:/home/xiaobai# exit
xiaobai@dnxb:~$ su xb
Password: 
xiaobai@dnxb:~$ pwd
/home/xiaobai
xiaobai@dnxb:~$ PS1='\u:\W\$ '
xiaobai:~$ exit
xiaobai@dnxb:~$ id
uid=1000(xiaobai) gid=1000(xiaobai) groups=1000(xiaobai),27(sudo)
xiaobai@dnxb:~$
```

It doesn't change to xb for PS1 '\u'. If so, how ?

Comment: The kernel know you as *1000*. When bash checks the name of *1000*, the first entry is your long name.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi I have to use startx to start gdm after i do this. It just hang when boot up.

Comment: No problem anymore after i remove this user from /etc/passwd and /etc/shadow.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What's wrong with setting manually?

```
PS1="xb@\h:\w\$ "
```

Comment: Thanks, my /home/xiaobai/.bash_aliases is symlink to /root/.bash_aliases, so it disrupt my thinking to put PS1 in the same file. But actually i can put PS1 in ~/.bashrc or do a simple uid checking to set PS1.

Comment: This is _not_ alias, it's better to use `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: Agree, setting PS1 should be handled in ~/.bashrc.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use the *same* `PS1` for both/all users, you can use parameter expansion to remove the vowels from the username:

```
PS1='${USER//[aeiou]}@\h:\w\$ '
```

Comment: Amazing, is this in the manual ? I can't found it in `man bash`.

Comment: It's here, under `${parameter/pattern/string}`: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html  (my man page calls it pattern substitution, but that web page doesn't seen have any descriptive names for the different expansions)